# Error usando punteros en C

Tags: c, punteros

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Hice la siguiente funcion para cambiar valores de dos variables de tipo enteras en el main pero el compilador me dice ese error, alguna idea?

Comment: Tienes dos instrucciones que no terminan en punto y coma.

Answer (score 0):

Es un error de sintaxis, tal como SuperG280 lo dijo. Al programar en C generalmente debés colocar un punto y coma al final de cada línea, obviamente hay excepciones, pero en tu caso no es relevante. Más allá de eso, tu código debería funcionar.

```c
void intercambiar(int* a, int* b)
{
    int tmp;
    tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}
```

Saludos.